# IdentityServer4 Invalid Redirect_Uri Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I created 3 separate projects, web api project, an web mvc project, and a asp.net core app. I am using IdentityServer4 with asp.net core identity. I have a project solution `id` that has the information of the `TestUsers`. On the line `RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:5444/signin-oidc"}`, I am redirecting it to the project `WeatherMVC`. The launchsettings.json on all three files are correct and so is the `RedirectUris` is correct. **Is there something that I am not doing correctly that is causing me to receive this message?**

[image]

[image]

**`weatherapi project`:**

`----startup.cs`:

```
namespace weatherapi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddIdentityServerAuthentication("Bearer", options =>
                {
                    options.ApiName = "weatherapi";
                    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5443";
                });

            services.AddControllers();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "weatherapi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "weatherapi v1"));
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`----launchsettings.json`:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52575",
      "sslPort": 44354
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "weatherapi": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore",
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5445;http://localhost:5002",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**`WeatherMVC Project`**:

`----launchsettings.json`:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:65206",
      "sslPort": 44398
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WeatherMVC": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5444;http://localhost:5001"
    }
  }
}
```

These two projects are under one solution which I perform a multiple startup projects.

On the other project, named `id`...

**`id project`**:

`----launchsettings.json`

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19916",
      "sslPort": 44341
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "id": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "hotReloadProfile": "aspnetcore",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5443;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

**inside of this class below `Config.cs`, I have the code where it will perform the `Redirect_uri`**:

```
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
          new[]
          {
        // m2m client credentials flow client
        new Client
        {
          ClientId = "m2m.client",
          ClientName = "Client Credentials Client",

          AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
          ClientSecrets = {new Secret("SuperSecretPassword".Sha256())},

          AllowedScopes = {"weatherapi.read", "weatherapi.write"}
        },

        // interactive client using code flow + pkce
        new Client
        {
          ClientId = "interactive",
          ClientSecrets = {new Secret("SuperSecretPassword".Sha256())},

          AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,

          RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:5444/signin-oidc"},
          FrontChannelLogoutUri = "https://localhost:5444/signout-oidc",
          PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:5444/signout-callback-oidc"},

          AllowOfflineAccess = true,
          AllowedScopes = {"openid", "profile", "weatherapi.read"},
          RequirePkce = true,
          RequireConsent = true,
          AllowPlainTextPkce = false
        },
          };
    }
}
```

`----startup.cs`:

```
public class Startup
    {
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
                .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(Config.ApiResources)
                .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
                .AddTestUsers(Config.Users)
                .AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute());

        }
    }
```

---

***UPDATE***

After adding the debugger in `program.cs` as suggested:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
            {
                builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                builder.AddFilter("IdentityServer4", LogLevel.Debug);
            });
```

I finally noticed that it is calling the redirect uri that belongs to the project named `WeatherMVC` using it's `sslPort: 44398`. Please see the `launchsettings.json` for that `weathermvc projcect`. Can't seem to understand why it is redirecting that URI if I do not have it set to that.

[image]

Comment: The IdentityServer logs have detailed information on errors. Turn logging on in program.cs like this  Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).ConfigureLogging(builder => { builder.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug); builder.AddFilter("IdentityServer4", LogLevel.Debug); })

Comment: Thank you, that helped me debug. I do not understand why it is redirecting to a uri that I did not set it to.... is that something that is causing this to incorrectly redirect? Sorry I am very new to this.

Comment: @Rosco Please see my updated post, under `Updated`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

WeatherApi is a client to IdentityServer and when it authenticates it tells IdentityServer its redirect uri. IdentityServer checks against its allowed redirect uris and redirects if it finds a match.

This code specifies a list of VALID redirect uris not THE redirect uri.

```cs
RedirectUris = {"https://localhost:5444/signin-oidc"},
```

You have IISExpress and also Kestrel setup in your `launchsettings.json` and I think your WeatherApi project is just using the first setting that it finds as the redirect uri.

Some possible solutions are:

Add the other uri for WeatherApi to the allowed uris e.g.

```cs
RedirectUris = {
  "https://localhost:5444/signin-oidc", "https://localhost:44398/signin-oidc"},
```

You can also change Kestrel in `launchsettings.json` for WeatherApi to use the same ports

```json
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44398;http://localhost:65206"
```

Comment: I understand now, that makes perfect sense! Thank you! To change the `launchsettings.json` under the `WeatherMVC` I had to write it as `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44398","http://localhost:65206"` because `"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44398;http://localhost:65206"` was saying invalid URL.

Comment: On another note, when I went to that path `/home/weather` on the WeatherMVC project browser, it made me login and asking for permission (like consenting) which is great... after logging in it displayed the random temperatures. After closing the application and reopening it, I went again to that path `/home/weather` and this time it did not redirect me to login (identity server) it just gave me the random temperatures. Is that normal with identity server? @Rosco

Comment: @NoviceCoder The token from Identityserver is valid for 1 hour (by default) so you shouldn't need to login

Comment: That's definitely great to know, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 4):

if anyone have similar problem with database. Check you uri in table.ClientRedirectUris

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I think your project is based on [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJQ2-sJURvA). This could be helpful for people to follow the steps involved. It also has a link to the code.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same error because I have missed added URLs with "http" whereas it requires "https". Confirm that you have added URLs with "https" and not the "http".

```
public static class RedirectUrls
{
    public const string WebSigninURI = "https://localhost:44332/signin-oidc";
    public const string WebSignOutURI = "https://localhost:44332/signout-callback-oidc";
}
```